In fine print: Refund Policy
Please accept my apology if this should be posted on English Stack Exchange or elsewhere.
I would like to take a person/organization to small claims court for not providing a refund. They ignore my messages. Don't even clarify.
The fine print: "Refund Policy: You can cancel your membership anytime. If you cancel your membership within the first 30 days of the first payment, you can receive a 100% refund."
Let's say I made first payment on Friday, June 7, 2024, 5pm. And cancelled the membership on Sunday, July 7, 2024, 8pm. They are closed on the weekend and open for business on Monday morning. Am I entitled to a refund? Basically, is this about days or the actual timestamp?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Am I entitled to a refund? Basically, is this about days or the actual
timestamp?

This would be a question of contract interpretation based upon all of the relevant facts and circumstances. I could see a court go either way on the question and we don't know whose courts (and hence which body of law) applies to interpreting it.
The smart thing to do would have been to try to cancel on Friday during business hours before the deadline.

trying to cancel on the monday after the sunday that the thing was due is clearly late.

@Trish Usually, although some jurisdictions have curative statutes that extend contractual deadlines that fall on Sundays and holidays.
